# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::save() fix it

Tags: laravel

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::save()

i am getting this error, while creating a new brand and a new category in my product page. please help me to fix it.

I tried creating pivot table but it dint work i guess in my scenario. Expecting the error to get resolved by.

Comment: hi , you should share your code so we can help you